# Bilingual mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, localization

I'm following the example here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/BilingualMvc3Part2.aspx

**Edit:** 
This solution works for Firefox, and IE, but not in Chrome. It is changing the culture (en to fr) but not appending the rest of the current route.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My GAC was not cleared, and the temp service created by visual studio had not been restarted. I have retested IE, firefox, and chrome with this solution and am not having any more troubles.